# python multiprocessing status of worker

Tags: python, backgroundworker, state, multiprocessing

I have a Python-interface class to a big C++ library, which does some work for me (with big amounts of data). I can gracefully stop the worker by sending it a signal, i.e. `os.kill( pid,signal.SIGINT )`.
So, I thought I should be able to run the worker in a `p = Process(target=worker.run() )` - which works - then at an arbitrary time interrupt the worker by sending it a signal - which works at well - but:

I cannot get the state of the worker back! There are several functions exported, which should give me information on what the worker was doing, but (obviously after calling `p.join()`), all these functions return, is the initial values. Why? (The worker actually did his work, which I can see in the created output-file, but I don't get the information there, which I'd want *during* work...)

Using a Queue or a Manager from multiprocessing doesn't seem to be an option, since the object is not really "pickleable", nor would I want to copy everything, if I just need the state of a specific variable in the worker. (I'm not at all sure that I have a firm grasp on this pickleable concept...)

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: As aix's answer suggests, it sounds like you are confusing multiprocessing with threading behavior.  The child process needs to communicate the state back to the parent process in some manner.  If the state that you want communicated back is a fundamental data type, there's not much you have to worry about as far as pickleability goes (http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 1):

In `multiprocessing`, workers run as separate processes. Each process has its own address (memory) space.

This means that if a worker changes a variable, the change won't be visible to the parent, unless [you've taken steps to make it visible](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I think I finally understood that. For some reason, I thought that 'joining' two processes again would magically retrieve the objects from the joined address-space. ;-) Actually, I find the name 'join' unfortunate, since nothing is really joined, the parent simply waits for the termination of the child, it seems.